# "No commands supplied" error when executing a Python script on Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, python, script

I checked out a SVN repository, and tried to `python setup.py` on my Ubuntu 10.04 terminal, which is a Python script, but I get the following error:

```
abc@def:~/Downloads/a-read-only$ python setup.py  
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]  
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]  
   or: setup.py --help-commands  
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I have no experience with Python, so any help I could get would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need to add a "cmd1".
to find out what that is, type

```
python setup.py --help
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use terminal command to install python from Ubuntu. Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

After Python has successfully installed. You could run the python terminal by typing 'python3' into the terminal and check if the command works. Or you could run the python scripts using:

```
python3 myfile.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a script called `setup.py` in your project (which clashes with the `python setup.py install` command), and you are importing it in the script you are trying to run.

Rename it, and your project should run fine (if that was the cause of the error).

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` can also contain calls to setup() with a `script_args` argument:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(ext_modules = [Extension(...)],
      script_args = ['build_ext'])
```

Although not clearly stated here
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/apiref.html, the build_ext command runs with:

```
$ python setup.py
```

without supplying a command to setup.py.